# Is it 2 cycle attracting?

Tags: calculus, recursion

Let $c$ be a constant and let $f(x) = x^3-3x+c$, $c>0$. Determine the values of c for which ${0,c}$ is a 2-cycle. Is the 2-cycle attracting for the value of $c$? Explain.

I am having trouble seeing why the solution is $c = ±√2$, and that in fact the {0,c} is 2-cycle repelling.

Comment: what you mean "2-cycle"?

Comment: $$f(c)=0 \implies c^3-3c+c=0 \implies c(c^2-2)=0\implies c=0,\pm \sqrt2$$ As for attracting/repelling we should look at $|f'(z)|$

Comment: I didn't know you can denote the x as c, because I ended up getting a strange function and tried to derive it but took long time. thank you for the explanation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can read [here](http://www.uwosh.edu/faculty_staff/kuennene/Chaos/ChaosNotes2.pdf) that

> for a function $f$ where $f^n(z_0)=z_0$  that $z_0$ is
>
> repelling when  $|(f^n)'(z_0)|>1$ and
>
> attracting  when  $|(f^n)'(z_0)|<1$.

$$f(x)=x^3-3x+c \implies f'(x)=3x^2-3$$

Take $c =\pm\sqrt2$; this means $f(c)=0, f'(c)=3$

$$\bigg(f(f(x)) \bigg)' =f'(f(x))f'(x)\implies f'(f(c))f'(c)=f'(0)f'(c)=-3\times 3=-9. $$

So then we have $f^2(c)=c \,$ and   $| (f^2)'(c)|>1$ and therefore $\{0, c \}$ is a repelling cycle.

Comment: thank you for the explanation. I know the theory behind it, it was just the way i derived the function.